# How to bend a logarithmic number line into a circle

Tags: graphics, logarithmic-scale

One way to plot a sequence of numbers on a logarithmic number line is this:

```
LogLogPlot[0, {t, 8, 16}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
 Ticks -> {{8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}}]
```

[image: logarithmic number line values 8 to 16]

How can the line be bent into a circle, or how can these values be plotted on a circle?

[image: logarithmic values 8 to 16 on circle]

The `ParametricPlot` function plots a circle around the coordinates when using `[{Sin[2 u], Cos[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]` and `Graphics[Circle[]]` draws a circle but I can't figure out how to put `Ticks` on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Approach with build-in `PolarTicks`:

```
PolarPlot[, {x, 0, 1}, PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
  PolarTicks -> Transpose@{π/2 - 2 π Rescale@Log[#], 
    Join[{""}, #[[2 ;; -2]], {ToString@#[[-1]] <> "/" <> ToString@#[[1]]}]}] &@ Range[8, 16]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, nice that you could use `PolarTicks`. I've usually found it easier to herd cats than to get `PolarTicks` to behave the way I want...

Answer (score 12):

```
set = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
logset = Log[set];
resc = 2 Pi Rescale[logset];
f[u_] := {Sin[u], Cos[u]};
markers = Line[{f[#], 1.1 f[#]}] & /@ resc;
labels = MapThread[
   Text[#1, 1.2 f[#2]] &, {set /. {8 -> "16/8", 16 -> ""}, resc}];
Graphics[{Circle[], markers, labels}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's probably best to ditch `ParametricPlot` and the like and build your own number line using graphics primitives. The following is my implementation (the code should be pretty easy to follow):

```
Clear@logCircle
logCircle[pts_] := 
    With[
        {
            θ = 360 Accumulate@Normalize[Differences[Log@pts], Total], 
            coord = {Sin[# Degree], Cos[# Degree]} &
        },
        Graphics[{
            Circle[],
            MapThread[
                Text[
                    If[# == Last@pts, # ~~ "/" ~~ First@pts, #] /. n_?NumericQ :> ToString@n, 
                    1.1 coord@#2
                ] &, 
                {Rest@pts, θ}
            ],
            Map[Line[{coord@#, 1.05 coord@#}] &, θ]
        }]
    ]

logCircle[Range[8, 16]]
```

[image]

Comment: How would your code look using `Rescale@logset` instead of `Accumulate@Normalize[Differences[Log@pts]`?

Comment: @Bogdan Replace `Accumulate@Normalize[...]` with `Rest@Rescale@Log@pts`. Rest of it remains the same, and you can use it with any set of ticks.

Answer (score 1):

(*Third version*) Here is the code as a function. `numlist` need not be a `Range`.

```
circlog[numlist_] := Block[{a,b}, {a,b} = numlist[[{1,-1}]];
Show[Graphics@{ Circle[{0,0},1],
{Text[If[# == a, SequenceForm[b,"/",a], #], 1.1 #2], Line@{#2, 1.04 #2}}&
@@@ ({#, Through[{Sin,Cos}[2Pi*Log[b/a,#/a]]]}& /@ Most@numlist) },
AspectRatio->Automatic]];
circlog@Range[8,16]
```

[image]

Comment: There's an extra `;` at the end of the code. The reason I didn't use `Range` is that this should work with any sequence of numbers; values 8 to 16 were easy to exemplify in a drawing. How would the code change when using `{8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}`?

Comment: The `;` at the end suppresses the unwanted `- Graphics -` message that 5.2 prints. I've updated the code to handle non-`Range` lists.

Comment: There's a `&` missing before the `@@@`. Now all I have to do is add another line and write `circlog[{8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}]`

Comment: Done, as requested.